# background position in mozila and ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this css

```
 .viewimages{position: fixed;}
```

which works in chrome and Mozilla but the position isn't picking in i.e instead it is floating left yet it is suppose to position itself in the center.So any help

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by adding a doctype to the top of your HTML document, forcing the browser to be a bit more standards compliant:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Or if you're using XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This will work unless you are relying on quirks mode to render the page then unfortunately there's no support.